# Turn columns into separate table with column name as values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on an extraction and I have an issue I can't quite solve.

My extraction looks like this :

```
+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| ID     | Info1 | Product1 | Product2 | ... | Product300 |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| 1      | Paul  | 2        |          |     |            |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| 2      | Steve |          | 1        |     |            |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| 3      | Mark  | 2        |          |     |            |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| ...    |       |          |          |     |            |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
| 150000 | Felix | 1        |          |     | 2          |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+-----+------------+
```

Products appear as columns. So it's not very easy to use.

I want to split my table with product as an external table like :

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| ID     | Product  | Value |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 1      | Product1 | 2     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 2      | Product2 | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| ...    |          |       |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 150000 | Product1 | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

Initially this extraction is in Excel but I moved to Access for this purpose.

I have basic knowledge of SQL but not enough to figure out a solution.

Comment: UNION ALL, 300 times.

Comment: What about `Info1 ` column. Is that required in final output?

Comment: @GauravKP That stays in the original table. Actually I have 30-ish columns of useful unique info and the next 300 are just products.

Comment: I dont have time to post an answer now but I would interrogate the equivalent of the SQL Server DMView that contains table structures.  Loop through the column names and build a dynamic insert into the new table.

Answer (score 1):

As jarlh wrote, the only SQL solution is this:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (ID, Product, Value)

SELECT ID, 'Product1' AS Product, Product1 AS Value FROM SrcTable WHERE Product1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'Product2' AS Product, Product2 AS Value FROM SrcTable WHERE Product2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
etc.
```

Maybe split it up into chunks, I'm not sure how well 300 UNION ALLs will work in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot your table:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

```
SELECT ID, Product, Value
FROM 
   (SELECT ID, Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, Product5
   FROM products) p
UNPIVOT
   (Value FOR Product IN 
      (Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, Product5)
)AS unpvt;
```

Comment: This should be in comment box as this doen't provide exact answer of above question. This can be treat as a suggestion to use and refer the provided link.

Comment: I don't have access to comment

Comment: @Janine During my searches I read about UNPIVOT.
I'm not entirely sure Access supports it.

Comment: Looks like it's called a transform in access:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: TRANSFORM in Access = PIVOT. There is no UNPIVOT in Access.